# how to pass elements of a list to a variable

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, variables, subprocess

```
def delete_events(self):


    self.ucn = self.user_channel_number
    print 'The channel number in the process: ', self.ucn

    self.bids = self.channel_events_book_ids
    print 'Events book ids', self.bids
    print '', len(self.bids), 'events on the planner will be deleted'

    are_you_sure = raw_input('Channel number is correct. Are you sure to delete channel number? (y/n): ') 

    if are_you_sure == 'y' and len(self.bids) !=0 :

        print 'The selected program will be deleted'

        action = 'DeleteEvent'
        menu_action = 'all'
        book = self.bids[0]
        arg_list = [('C:\\Users\\yke01\\Documents\\StormTest\\Scripts\\Completed'
                        '\\Utils\\UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line.py')]
        arg_list.append(' --action=')
        arg_list.append(action)
        arg_list.append(' --ip=')
        arg_list.append('10.10.8.89')
        arg_list.append(' --objectId=')
        arg_list.append(book)

        subprocess.call(["python", arg_list])

        print 'The program deleted successfully'

    else: 
        print 'The program is NOT deleted!'
```

I have got a list of book ids. And I would like to pass these numbers to book variable to delete events.

```
output of bookids samples : ['BOOK:688045640', 'BOOK:688045641', 'BOOK:688045642', 'BOOK:688045643', 'BOOK:688045644', 'BOOK:688045645', 'BOOK:688045646', 'BOOK:688045647']
```

I can get delete a single event with the following action:

```
book = self.bids[0]
```

How I can pass bookids list elements to book variable ?

Comment: Have you tried with "for" loop?

Again do you want to pass 'BOOK:688045640' or only '688045640' to the "--objectId=" argument

Answer (score 0):

In your current code you are doing:

```
book = self.bids[0]
# ...
arg_list.append(book)
```

which is equivalent to

```
arg_list.append(self.bids[0])
```

which appends a single item from the `self.bids` list to the `arg_list` list. To add the whole `self.bids` list to the end of `arg_list`, use the `.extend` method instead:

```
arg_list.extend(self.bids)
```

Another option is to use the `+=` assignment operator which will extend the existing list:

```
arg_list += self.bids
```

---

BTW, your `subprocess.call(["python", arg_list])` is a bit strange. As shown in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call), it should be

```
subprocess.call(["python"] + arg_list)
```

However, it would be much more efficient to import the UPNP_Client_Cmd_Line module and call its functions directly.